# launch.vs.json with custom PATH or

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am building a project in one folder (build), to run the program I need additional files and folders that are in another folder (env_folder).

I read that the launch is configured by the file launch.vs.json and it is possible to define variables in the array "env", I tried to define the variable PATH:<env_folder> in this array and it worked only for files but not for the folders nested in env_folder. Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What kind of C++ project ? Just to confirm, are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I use Visual Studio.  CMake project